# Every smooth cubic curve has a flex point

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I want to show that every smooth irreducible plane cubic $C$ has a flex point, i.e. a point $P$ with $i_P(C, T_C(P)) = 3)$ (where $T_C(P)$ is the tangent to $C$ at $P$). I know how to do this in characteristic zero - take the Hessian and use Bezout's theorem - but don't know how to proceed in characteristic $p$. Can anyone provide a proof or point me to a resource where this is shown? I'm fine with chracteristic $\neq 2,3$.

Comment: Is it really necessary to apply Bézout's theorem? There's a weak form that you can prove by hand that says that any two projective plane curves must intersect.

Comment: @ZhenLin I suppose not, and I do have that weaker form, but this isn't homework so I'm just looking for a good way to see it.

Answer (score 1):

For characteristic $\not=2,3$ you can always put the curve in short Weierstrass form and choose the point at infinity. I'm not sure about char=$2,3$.

EDIT:
For characteristic 2 or 3 we can put the curve in [Weierstrass form](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticCurve.html), and again the only point at infinity will be $[0:1:0]$, with tangent equal to $Z$, and the tangent will intersect the curve three times in that point, making it a flex.