# Irreducibility for cubics and existence of inflection points

Tags: irreducible-polynomials, elliptic-curves, intersection-theory

Consider a nonzero homogenuous degree three polynomial $P\in k[X,Y,Z]$ in $3$ variables with coefficients in a field $k$ of characteristic $\neq 2, 3$.

1. How can one check whether $P$ is irreducible? Is there an analogue for cubics of the discriminant of a quadratic form that decides this question for conics?
2. In the first paragraph [here](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/elliptic/weier.html) it is claimed that an irreducible cubic either has an inflection point or a singular point, and that this follows from Bezout's theorem. Could someone provide details?

I'm starting to learn about elliptic curves : these are some elementary questions I couldn't find answers to online. Regarding the first point, all I have found is [this fact](https://mathoverflow.net/a/118956/13700) which implies that the equation of an elliptic curve in Weierstrass form is irreducible as a polynomial $\in k[X,Y]$. I'm not quite sure whether this fact is answers my first question. Certainly irreducibility of the Weierstrass normal form should imply irreducibility of the homogeneous cubic $P$.

Reducing the equation of an elliptic curve to Weierstrass form requires as far as I understand, sending the flex point and its tangent line to the line at infinity, thus the existence of flex points is important.

Comment: For 2. see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366837/every-smooth-cubic-curve-has-a-flex-point) and [this pdf on Jan Stevens' homepage](http://www.math.chalmers.se/~stevens/bezout.pdf)

Comment: Bezout's theorem also implies that a reducible cubic defines a curve with a singular point. This is because the points of intersection of the curves determined by the factors are singular (their coordinates may be in an extension field of $k$ though).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thank you, this makes sense. Is the converse true aswell : if the cubic is smooth (say over an algebraic closure) then the underlying cubic polynomial is irreducible ?

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland thank you for the reference. I've been going over it in the past two days.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Also, I'm totally new to algebraic geometry, so please forgive these elementary questions : is being smooth defined / equivalent to having an equation $f$ whose pointwise gradient $(\partial_{X_1}f,\dots,\partial_{X_n}f)$ along the variety $f=0$ is everywhere nonzero ?

Comment: Olivier, I don't think so. Consider the (homogenization of) Foil of Descartes: $X^3+Y^3=3XYZ$. That cubic has a singularity at the origin, but it is irreducible. For if that cubic were a product of a linear and a quadratic the curve would be a union of a line and a conic which it manifestly isn't.

Comment: Yes, that's equivalent to smoothness. In higher dimensions (with several constraint equations) you need the Jacobian to have full rank. IIRC smoothness is often defined a bit differently, but it comes to that rank condition for the Jacobian. In general you get one to the Jacobian for each generator of the ideal of polynomials vanishing on the variety.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Regarding your counter example, I should have mentioned that I was interested in the projective curve it defines. Everything I'm interested in is projective. It seems that any homogeneous polynomial of degree $\geq 2$ should have a singularity at he origin.

Comment: Sorry about not making this clear. The Foil of Descartes has a singularity at the origin of the affine chart $Z=1,x=X/Z,y=Y/Z$. In other words, at the point $[X:Y:Z]=[0:0:1]$ = the origin of that affine chart. The singularity is obvious in the plot of that real plane curve. Smoothness at a point of a projective curve can always be tested in an affine chart containing it.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you ! So it's a little more complicated than I had hoped ^^. Do you know whether there is a, say, numerical invariant that characterizes irreducibility of a projective cubic curve ? Also I think I now remember a fact I read without proof : if an irreducible cubic has a singularity it is unicursal, in that there is a algebraic map that is a bijection $\mathbb{P}^1\to C$, which I can now see clearly (in principle) using the double point, the projective line of lines through that point and Bézout's theorem. So is there a trichotomy? Smooth, double point and reducible?

Comment: Ok, this can't be correct as is, since reducible curves will be non smooth at the intersection points of its components.

Comment: I'm not 100% but I think that trichotomy holds. If an irreducible plane cubic has a singularity, then the function field has genus zero which is equivalent to the curve having a rational parametrization, which is equivalent to having that algebraic map from the projective line. For example, the Foil has the well known parametrization $x=3t/(1+t^3), y=3t^2/(1+t^3)$, with $t$ ranging over the projective line. The parametrization arising from blowing up the singularity at $(x,y)=(0,0)$.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm rather ignorant about the theory. Many people have recommended Fulton's book on curves as giving a very thorough and a very accessible account of this. It concentrates on characteristic zero, but that rarely plays a role.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you very much for indulging me, this exchange was very helpful. I'll check out that book, it seems to be available for free on his webpage.

Comment: BTW, I once answered the wrong question. Yes, if a cubic curve is smooth over an algebraic closure, then the polynomial is irreducible. The Foil is only an example of a cubic that is irreducible but also has a singularity. This probably became clear from the discussion but I'm recording this for the sake of completeness