# Does every nonsingular cubic curve $C \subset \mathbb{P}^2$ over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ have a flex over $\mathbb{F}_{q^3}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, finite-fields, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves, cubics

I cannot prove the following statement.

> Does every nonsingular cubic curve $C \subset \mathbb{P}^2$ over a finite field
>   $\mathbb{F}_q$ have a flex over $\mathbb{F}_{q^3}$?

Is there an elegant proof (i.e., without the full brute force of possible Frobenius actions on the [Hesse configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hesse_configuration) of 9 flexes of $C$) or at least a reference to some source?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Every smooth cubic curve has a flex point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366837/every-smooth-cubic-curve-has-a-flex-point)

Comment: This is not the answer, because I ask about the finite field case.  A cubic may have no a flex over $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but is there a reason to expect that $\mathbf F_{q^3}$ is the right extension, rather than something bigger?

Answer (score 1):

The question linked in the comments provides a reasonable strategy. Suppose we have a smooth cubic over $\Bbb F_q$ given by the equation $f(X,Y,Z)=0$. If we can put the curve in to Weierstrass form $Y^2Z+a_1XYZ+a_3YZ^2 = X^3+a_2X^2Z+a_4XZ^2+a_6Z^3$ over $\Bbb F_{q^3}$, then we will be done: if we have such a Weierstrass form for our curve, then the point $[0:1:0]$ is on our curve, and the tangent line is given by $Z$, which intersects our cubic with multiplicity 3 at $[0:1:0]$, giving a flex.

**Lemma**. Given any homogeneous cubic defined over $\Bbb F_q$, we may put the cubic in to Weierstrass form over $\Bbb F_{q^3}$ via a projective change of coordinates.

**Proof**: By a standard argument, any smooth cubic with a $K$-rational point may be put in to a Weierstrass form over $K$ via a projective change of coordinates ([here](https://ctnt-summer.math.uconn.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/1632/2016/02/Matsuura-projective_transformation.pdf), or any elliptic curve book). We claim that a smooth cubic defined over $\Bbb F_q$ always has a rational point over $\Bbb F_{q^3}$, which will show the claim.

Intersect our cubic $C$ with any $\Bbb F_q$-rational line (for instance, the $Z$-axis). By Bezout, this intersection is of degree three over $\Bbb F_q$. Thus either it contains a $\Bbb F_q$-rational point or it contains a point defined over a cubic extension of $\Bbb F_q$. But $\Bbb F_q$ has only one cubic extension (up to isomorphism): $\Bbb F_{q^3}$. So $C$ has a rational point over $\Bbb F_{q^3}$ and we're done. $\blacksquare$

One could also just get one's hands dirty with the equation of the curve: there it will be obvious that you need access to $\Bbb F_{q^3}$-coefficients (and no other extensions) to make the relevant coordinate changes. This is very low-tech, which has it's advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: You are right that every $\mathbb{F}_q$-cubic has an $\mathbb{F}_q$-point $P$ and we can put it in to Weierstrass form over $\mathbb{F}_q$. However, this is not a projective change of coordinates if P is not a flex, but only isomorphism of algebraic curves. In particular, the property to be a flex is not invariant under this isomorphism.

Comment: Really? That's quite surprising to me - do you have an example handy?